# How to do nothing if the same option is selected in an Android dialog?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-dialog

I have the following dialog:

```
val alertDialog: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
val options = arrayOf("Red", "Blue", "Green")
alertDialog.setTitle("Select a color")
alertDialog.setSingleChoiceItems(options, 1) { dialog, position ->
    logErrorMessage("position: " + position)
    dialog.dismiss()
}
val alert: AlertDialog = alertDialog.create()
alert.show()
```

The default selected value that is is "Blue", as I pass `1` to `setSingleChoiceItems`. Every time I click on one of the three options, I get the `position` printed. Is there any way I can get that log statement only if the option is changed? If the same option remains selected, then I want no log statement? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you don't change the default selected value, just do a conditional check that the position isn't equal to `1`. If it's more dynamic, then store the current position and compare that instead:

```
val alertDialog: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
val options = arrayOf("Red", "Blue", "Green")
alertDialog.setTitle("Select a color")
alertDialog.setSingleChoiceItems(options, 1) { dialog, position ->
    if(position != 1) {
         logErrorMessage("position: " + position)
    }
    dialog.dismiss()
}
val alert: AlertDialog = alertDialog.create()
alert.show()
```

Comment: it should be quite simple to just store the last position in a static variable and to compare that